# Traceroute method to print the route that packets follow to a network host

Tags: 16.04, networking, proxy, network-monitoring, traceroute

Is there a particular traceroute method/options to print the route that packets follow to a network host, *include* showing the possible proxy servers and a network tap that installed on the link between the customer-provided equipment (modem) and ISP CMTS (head-end).

Comment: Proxy servers operate at a specific protocol, generally application specific, such as http. Traceroute operates at layer 3 in the OSI model. Your modem typically operates at layer 2. Traceroute will only show L3 devices, generally speaking.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but a traceroute - like `mtr` does nothing but print the route, only it shows IP addressed hops only. `arp` will show local network devices - like a router or other client. What are you trying to do, what specific provider and equipment are you working with?

Comment: Not shure that fully understand the question. May be you need `sudo aptitude install etherape` and look the network trafic

Comment: I mean can we via command somehow reveal and designate (IP, device name) the passive network TAPs installed somewhere on the route between the client modem and ISP head-end (CMTS). The TAPs are used to monitor network.